# Captcha response while retrieving access_token

Tags: stocktwits

I'm now testing custom sharing flow in StockTwits and got stuck on authorizing the user. 
I'm following the server-side oauth flow described [here.](https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication)

I'm using an npm lib `stocktwits`, but I've already tried this request from terminal using curl:
`curl -X POST https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/token -d 'client_id=439fb********3e6&client_secret=5420fa774******970c24f074b90e617&code=ccb99afde1**********de6d782029c68&grant_type=authorization_code'`

After getting the **code** I call the `https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/token (POST)` to perform exchange for **access_token** but I get an unexpected response with HTML in it asking to bypass a captcha instead of JSON like described in [here.](https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#oauth-token-docs)

Comment: I also have this problem, it looks like cloudflare protection intervenes with the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve the issue with server side flow. My purpose was to authorize in any possible way, so I just switched from server-side flow to client side and it works just fine. both approaches are described [here](https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication)

Comment: Please explain how you achieved that, otherwise this is not an answer. If you do not know how the problem got fixed, then the question qualifies as "not reproducable" and should be deleted.

Comment: @Yunnosch
I didn't solve the issue with server side flow. My purpose was to authorize in any possible way, so I just switched from server-side flow to client side and it works just fine.

both approaches are described [here](https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication)

Comment: Now that seems a nice explanation, which makes a helpful answer. But please accept my apology, I can see now that the core information was already there. Nevertheless, consider [edit]ing the longer version into the answer itself.